# The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.0 Authentication Required. C# WFM

Tags: c#

Hello i am trying to send an email from c# desktop program but i get this error:

**The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.0 Authentication Required.**

This is my code:

```
string fromAddress = "xy@gmail.com";
            string fromPassword = "xy";
            string toAddress = "az61@gmail.com";
            string subject = "Test";
            string body = "Hello :D";

            SmtpClient smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
            {
                smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                smtp.Port = 587;
                smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                smtp.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                smtp.Timeout = 20000;
                smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress, fromPassword);
            }
            smtp.Send(fromAddress, toAddress, subject, body);
            MessageBox.Show("Success!");
```

Comment: Is your gmail account allowing less secure apps? Check setting under security section.

Comment: Try port 465. By the way, you need to dispose the client

Answer (score 0):

Try making sure of the following:

1. Your gmail account allows [Less secure app access](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps).
2. Set `smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;` before setting `smtp.Credentials`.